# Change order of integration (Jacobian?)

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not really sure how to complete this problem. Usually I would draw the region, but what should I do if I don't think I can draw it? These regions look a little tricky to draw. Can I use the Jacobian?

The problem is:

Change the order of integration, then transform the integral using polar coordinates:

$$ \int f(x,y) dydx, $$ $$a>0 $$ $$ 0≤x≤2a  $$
$$ \sqrt{2ax-x^2}≤y≤\sqrt{2ax}  $$

Comment: Is the square root on the right hand side of the inequality only over the 2 or everything? I only ask because of the way you've written the left hand one

Comment: edited! It's over everything.

Comment: I suggested another edit please review it and see if that's what you mean, typically curly brackets enclose expressions as arguments of functions

Comment: Yes, that edit is correct. thanks :)

Comment: As for the problem it will help to visualize the region if you make an example using a specific value of a, say a=1. The right hand side is fairly easy to visualize if you are familiar with the square root function in general. The left hand side is an upside down parabola shaped function.

Answer (score 1):

You have $3$ boundary curves, the circle $(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$, the parabola opening right $y^2=2ax$, and the vertical line $x=2a$. The region of integration thus looks something like this:
[image: Figure 1]

In polar coordinates, the circle becomes $2ar\cos\theta-r^2\cos^2\theta=r^2\sin^2\theta$ or $r=2a\cos\theta$. The parabola reads $r^2\sin^2\theta=2ar\cos\theta$ or $r=2a\cot\theta\csc\theta$. The vertical line is $r\cos\theta=2a$ or $r=2a\sec\theta$. The integral is subdivided where the vertical line and the parabola cross, so $2a\sec\theta=2a\cot\theta\csc\theta$, so $\cot^2\theta=1$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}4$. Now we can write the integral in polar coordinates
$$\begin{align}\int\int_Rf(x,y)d^2 A&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4}\int_{2a\cos\theta}^{2a\sec\theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)r\,dr\,d\theta\\
&+\int_{\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_{2a\cos\theta}^{2a\cot\theta\csc\theta}f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\,r\,dr\,d\theta\end{align}$$
Are you also supposed to write the integral out in rectangular coordinates?